# issue C++ with alghorithm mountain

Tags: c++

Hy i have the following problem: 
A number has a mountain appearance if its figures are in ascending order up to the middle of the number and in descending order from that position. Example: 12321, 345754 are mountain-view numbers. For a natural number n read from the pc user, please check to see if the number has a mountain appearance, displaying an appropriate message.
I have made this but i don't know where is the issue:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {
     int n, k = 0, x, middle, ok, i, up;
     cout << "n=";
     cin >> n;
     x = n;
     while (x) {
         k++;
         x /= 10;
     }
     if (k % 2 == 0) middle = k / 2;
     else middle = k / 2 + 1;

     ok = 1;
     up = n % 10;
     for (i = 0; i <= up && ok != 1; i++) {
         n = n / 10;
         if (up > n % 10) ok = 0;
     }
     if (ok == 1) {
         up = n % 10;
         for (i = k - up; i < 0 && ok == 1; i--) {
             n = n / 10;
             if (up < n % 10)
             ok = 0;
         }
         if (ok == 1)
             cout << "Evrika! Your number has a mountain appearance";
         else
             cout << "No mountain appearance";
     } else
         cout << "No mountain appearance"; 
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy, you have on line 17 some mistake:
replace

```
for (i = 0; i <= up && ok != 1; i++)
```

with

```
 for(i=0;i<=middle && ok==1;i++)
```

and in the next for:

```
for (i = k - up; i < 0 && ok == 1; i--) {
```

you write this:

```
for(i=k-middle;i>0 && ok==1;i--)
```